# Concatenate lines in two files

Tags: python

Consider the following two files:

file1.txt:

```
    file1line1
    file1line2
    file1line3
```

file2.txt

```
    file2line1
    file2line2
    file2line2
```

I want to combine each line in file1 with the corresponding line in file2.

How can this be done in python.

You can assume that the number of lines is equal in both files.

Comment: So you're looking for Python equivalent of `paste`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With `zip()` you can easily do this:

```
with open('file1.txt') as fh1, open('file2.txt') as fh2:
    for line1, line2 in zip(fh1, fh2):
        # line1 from file1, line2 from file2
```

If you are using Python 2 this does load all of both files into memory; use `itertools.izip()` instead to read lines as needed:

```
from itertools import izip

with open('file1.txt') as fh1, open('file2.txt') as fh2:
    for line1, line2 in izip(fh1, fh2):
        # line1 from file1, line2 from file2
```

In Python 3, `zip()` behaves as `itertools.izip()`.

Comment: Nice! I didn't know about the option to include two contexts in one `with` statement.

Comment: @HansZauber: You'll need Python 2.7 or 3.x for this to work; in 2.6 (and 2.5 with `from future import with_statement`) you can only use one context manager at a time per `with` statement.

Comment: Thanks. One more little question though: Under `for line1, line2 in zip(fh1, fh2):` I have added `print line1+line2` and they are printed in separate lines.  How can I get line1 and line2 be printed at the same line, one next to the other?

Comment: @Subway: Lines are read from the file *with the line terminators*. Use `line.rstrip('\n')` to remove it.

Comment: If you use `itertools.izip_longest` you can also handle the case where a file is longer then the other: `izip_longest(fh1, fh2, fillvalue="")`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a much less "pythonic" solution, which might be more readable for some of us:

```
lines1 = open('file1.txt').read().split('\n')
lines2 = open('file2.txt').read().split('\n')
combined_lines = []
for i in range(len(lines1)):
   combined_lines.append(lines1[i] + lines2[i])
```

Comment: I don't find this to be more readable; by a long shot. Note that `file.readlines()` will return a list of lines (no need to use `.read().split('\n')` here). You can use `combined_lines = zip(lines1, lines2)` as well.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - well, readability is subjective. python has a lot of options to make the code more minimal, but makes it harder for beginners to understand whats happening, and your answer would be a good example of that. This is just braking down all the iterations happening anyway.